# odbc datetime convertion in erlang

Tags: sql, erlang

Because of some reason,need convert sql time-stamp YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS into erlang time form {{Y,M,D},{H,M,S}}.

fortunately when I query the database the Return Value is already formed as {{Y,M,D},{H,M,S}}.

like:

```
     [{4,null,null,null,null,
              {{2012,12,17},{14,54,4}}, % time-stamp already convert
                                        % from 2012-12-17 14:54:04
                    0,678,51,61}]
```

and then also need convert erlang time form {{Y,M,D},{H,M,S}} into SQL time-stamp Form  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,
after some search there is no such direct function to do it. 
so I write the fun like below

```
 my_time() ->
      {{Y,Mo,D},{H,Mi, S}} = erlang:localtime(),
      TSString = 
    integer_to_list(Y)++"-"++ 
            integer_to_list(Mo)++"-"++ 
            integer_to_list(D)++" "++
        integer_to_list(H) ++ ":" ++ 
            integer_to_list(Mi) ++ ":" ++ 
            integer_to_list(S),
      TSString.
```

It works, but I don't like it. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using lib_io:format() would clean it up a bit:

```
my_time() ->
 {{Y,Mo,D},{H,Mi, S}} = erlang:localtime(),
 io_lib:format("~4.10.0B-~2.10.0B-~2.10.0B ~2.10.0B:~2.10.0B:~2.10.0B", [Y, Mo, D, H, Mi, S]).
```